# 2 questions about "Cast Away"

Tags: cast-away

I have two question about the movie [*Cast Away*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162222/):

1. After a few days in the island, Chuck Noland's body was full of injuries and wounds. Why didn't any of them get infected?
2. What is the meaning of the last scene? (Chuck, looking toward the ranch or maybe the truck.)

Comment: Since those two questions are completely unrelated, it would be a better idea to make those separate questions in order to facilitate individual assessment and answers.

Comment: Yeah, if one person answers 1 very well and another 2 very well ...... who gets the 'accept' prize?  Really this would be better as two questions.

Comment: I answered both very well so no need to worry.

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/can-we-please-split-this-question

Comment: Please note its likely that I will shortly delete question 2 from this and make it a separate community wiki question.

Comment: @iandotkelly: Whilst I don't want to go against the guidelines, is that _really_ necessary. 10 people have viewed the meta question, with just you and atticae commenting on it. However, some 15 people to date have upvoted the double answer on here? Can the question not simply be edited to make it a little clearer as opposed to separating it out?

Comment: @AndrewMartin *"Can the question not simply be edited to make it a little clearer as opposed to separating it out?"* - The problem is that those two questions aren't related in *any* way. It's not that there could be *any* connection constructed with some alternative wording (though, unfortunately it's rather the 1st one that could be deleted, but that just as a side note).

Answer (score 16):

1. Why should they? Or better: They probably did but that normally is not as serious as your question implies. The human body's immune system is made exactly for this. You need to be quite unlucky to get a deadly infection from surface wounds. And as a frequent traveler, his vaccinations certainly were up to date. Probably he would have retained more visual marks in reality than there were in the last scenes.
2. A new beginning, new choices, a fresh start, several roads to choose from, don't mourn the ex but search for new people. A new life, a rebirth, for the bureaucracy a literal one (as his colleague mentions who did the paperwork - Chuck should be forever grateful for that). But an open end, he can begin a new life as he pleases, a chance you seldom get. It's good that the filmmakers didn't explicitly answer that one.

Answer (score 4):

As far as question #1 goes, salt water does wonders for healing abrasions and cuts.

Question #2. He's looking at the truck because he wants to go back and pursue the woman who he dropped the package off to.